# VBA ListBox PivotTable Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro that creates a pivot table that filters based on a users selection from a list box. It first creates the pivot table and then adds the filters based on the listbox selection. Here is an example:

```
If ListBox1 = ("Fred") Then
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Employee").CurrentPage = _
    "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Employee")
    .PivotItems("Tom").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("John").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("Mary").Visible = False
End If
```

To further elaborate, if the user selects Fred in the ListBox, it filters out all other employees, in this case, Tom, John, and Mary.

Here is the issue. One of the ListBoxes I'm creating allows for the user to select multiple items. This means I'd need to hard code all combinations/permutations of the items into vba. Is there a way I could do this without individually coding every possible user choice combination?

Please let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Thanks,

KJ

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply get them to make their selections via a Slicer?

Comment: The person I’m doing this for doesn’t want any slicers. However if it’s something VBA really can’t do, I just need confirmation so I can go in a different direction.